# How do I send a variable to MySQL using PowerShell?

Tags: mysql, powershell, variables

Currently on a small project, I need to send a variable to a mysql command
here is the current code:

```
$var="expl_inst"
$Mysql="<chemin>/Uploads"
$date=Get-Date -Format "yyMMddHHmm"
mysql --defaults-file=<chemin>\my.ini <databases> -e "set @test:='$var'; source I:\M...\export.sql"
```

script SQL :

```
select * from @test INTO OUTFILE '<chemin>\test.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

error :

```
mysql : ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\M'.
Au caractère Ligne:5 : 1
+ mysql --defaults-file=<chemin>\my.ini <database> -e "s ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\M'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

How can I resolve my concern?
How can I get my SQL script to accept a variable from my Powershell script?

thank you

Comment: Try using `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: Where ? 
on all my command lines?
I try "mysql --defaults-file=<chemin>\my.ini automatorrpt -e "set @test:=`'$var`'; source I:/M.../export.sql" and i have : mysql : ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source 
I:/M.../export.sql' at line 1

Comment: Well as its complaining about `\M` and this is the only `\M` I would start by trying to change this `source I:\M...\export.sql"` to `source I:/M.../export.sql"`

Comment: On Windows, each \  in the source path needs to be escaped as \\.

Comment: Until the time to use the "" set @test: = `'$ var`';" it worked, the source has no problem without the set